# Neovim autocompletion in sass files

Tags: sass, autocomplete, neovim

I recently started using neovim and can't find how to enable autocompletion in sass files.
In css and scss everything works fine. But in files like text.sass - no.

Are there any solutions? Plugins? I will be grateful for any help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdlcp.png)

I installed cssls server but it doesn't seem to support sass.